# Can I fill a prompt for the proxy authentificacion with Selenium (and python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, authentication, proxy

I have this code working but I have to write the user and password for the proxy every single time I run the script. Is there a way to fill those two fields in the prompt (user/password)?

```
proxy = {'host': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 'port': 12345, 'usr': "AAAAAAA", 'pwd': "BBBBBBB"}
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.http', proxy['host'])
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', int(proxy['port']))
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.no_proxies_on', 'localhost, 127.0.0.1')
fp.set_preference('signon.autologin.proxy', 'true')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyip.com")
```

Comment: Please identify your proxy auth prompt is a JavaScript pop-up or System/native pop-up.   If  JavaScript pop-up, you can use selenium to input username/password by sendKeys(), otherwise you need to use 3rd-party python library which can capture/operate any opened window on OS

Comment: It´s a native pop up, so I guess I must use a third party tool... do you know anyone?

Comment: is there any reason you don't want use the `selenium.webdriver.common.proxy.Proxy` class with your Firefox profile?

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason you want to fill the form rather than provide it in your `FirefoxProfile()`? you can build your entire proxy profile by using `selenium.webdriver.common.proxy`, but you can also set the username and password through `.set_preference` as you're doing with the rest of your code. try adding the following to your code:

```
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", proxy['usr'])
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", proxy['pwd'])
```

EDIT (`Proxy()` method):

without knowing your proxy info, maybe try the following, which is what i use. it uses selenium's `Proxy()` functionality on top of `FirefoxProfile()`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *


proxy = {'host': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 'port': 12345, 'usr': "AAAAAAA", 'pwd': "BBBBBBB"}

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('signon.autologin.proxy', 'true')
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.share_proxy_settings', 'false')
fp.set_preference('network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies', 'false')
fp.set_preference('network.auth.use-sspi', 'false')

proxy_address = '%s:%s' % (proxy['host'], int(proxy['port']))
proxy_dict = {'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
              'httpProxy': proxy_address,
              'ftpProxy': proxy_address,
              'sslProxy': proxy_address,
              'noProxy': '',
              'socksUsername': proxy['usr'],
              'socksPassword': proxy['pwd']}

proxy_config = Proxy(proxy_dict)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy_config, firefox_profile=fp)
```

Comment: That would be a perfectly valid option too @crookedleaf, but the propmpt is still there, anything I´m missing?

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.http', proxy['host'])
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', int(proxy['port']))
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", proxy['usr'])
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", proxy['pwd'])
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.no_proxies_on', 'localhost, 127.0.0.1')
fp.set_preference('signon.autologin.proxy', 'true')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)

Comment: @torpedete hmm. try using the `Proxy()` method. i just updated my answer to show how to set it up.

Comment: with your code and  **driver.get("http://www.whatsmyip.com")** (with http://), the browser loads the page but I´m getting always the same ip, it´s like the proxy is not being used, actually it´s not being used. I´m trying different proxies from different locations and I keep seeing the same IP